# Where can I find list of changes I made in excel worksheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I made some changes in my excel worksheet and want to view for the list of changes I made, however, the history sheet is not displaying after I click the "OK" button in the Highlight changes dialog box. I watched the video about Track changes, and part of the video shows that after clicking "OK" button the history (list of changes) sheet is displaying. I expect the same thing I saw in the video,

These are the steps I followed:

1. Click Review > Track Changes > Highlight Changes.
2. Under Highlight which changes, select the When check box and then, in the When list, click All.
3. Clear the Who and Where check boxes.

4.Select the List changes on a new sheet check box.

5. Click OK.

- 

*# In the history worksheet, click the filter arrows next to the column labels to find the information that you want*.

## *

Comment: " the same thing I saw in the video," <-- which video?

Comment: Track changes only work of changes you make AFTER turning it on. Anything before you'll have to rely on Version History (if saved to one drive/sharepoint) or possibly Manage Workbook. Good luck.